# Parser: The syntax for the ImpersonationInfo object is incorrect, If the ImpersonateAccount value is used for ImpersonationInfo

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to deploy a cube for the first time on my PC.  I have run SSMS as an Admin and made myself (Gary-pc\gary, using Windows authentication) an admin. Doing this got me past the error message user does not have permission to create a new object in 'GARY-PC', or the object does not exist.
When I deploy the cube now, I get the error: the syntax for the ImpersonationInfo object is incorrect. If the ImpersonateAccount value is used for ImpersonationInfo, then the Account property cannot be empty.
I have not (knowingly! LOL) set up anything related to impersonation.

Comment: solved the problem, documenting for future reference. 
the link below  provides info on how to change the impersonation (double click on the data source, select impersonation..). I changed to 'use credentials of user' and was able to deploy 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/9adc7789-da4b-4e56-8814-365ea9c4ceba

However,   when I tried to process it , it said ‘impersonation method does not support processing’.

So I changed to use the service account. And was able to process successfully. I am now able to browse the cube. Hooray!

Answer (score 17):

I've resolved the problem with this:

- Double click on data source
- Select impersonation
- Choose use credentials of user

As @user1335419 says.

Answer (score 2):

I tried changing the impersonation to "Credentials of User" and although I was successful in deploying the cube, I could not process it.  I ended up getting an error that said:

> "The datasource contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported
>   for processing operations"

So I changed the impersonation from "Credentials of User" to "Inherit" and was able to process.  I don't know if the first deployment would have worked with "Inherit", but thought I would share my experience.

Comment: I got the same error and was able to resolve it using the manually entered credentials. Inherit may be best though when considering password changes.